# how to subreference in floatrow package - hyperref?

Tags: graphics, subfig, floatrow

I have a subfigure environment using the floatrow package and I would like to reference each figure in the panel individually in my paragraph as follows:

figure (3a) and figure (3b)
but it somehow does not work, when I call the `\subref` command.

my full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[figure]{subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, 
            labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:mHCN2_dime}]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figs/Fig_edited_figure_A_in_panel.png}\label{fig:a}%
}
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2}]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figs/mHCN2_cAMP_hidden_rotated_90_non-swapped_packing.png}\label{fig:a}%
}

\caption{Structure of the channel tetramer in the ligand-free state, viewed parallel to the membrane (A) or from the extracellular side (B). Each subunit is shown in a different color. Gray bars represent approximate boundaries of the membrane bilayer.}

\label{fig:mHCN2}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is hopefully not your full code. Make your code compilable and replace the figures by example-image or use simply text.

Comment: BTW, reqno is an amsmath option (right equation number) which is the default anyway.

Comment: \subref is defined by the subcaption package.   \sidesubfloat is supported by the subfig package.  The two are incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provides a `subcaption` compatible version of `\sidesubfloat`.

The tricky bit is that caption (even `\captiontext`) always fills the space given, so we need to measure the needed space first by faking it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\sidesubfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption and \label (optional}, #2 image
{\begin{subcaptiongroup}
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}% get width of caption
  \sbox0{(\thesubfigure)~#1~}% assumed format
  \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}%
  \sbox1{#2}% get width of image
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd1\relax
  \ifdim\dimen0>\wd0
    \dimen0=\wd0
  \fi
  \setbox2=\vbox{\hsize=\dimen0\caption{#1}}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr \abovecaptionskip+\ht1-\ht2}[\ht1]{\usebox2}#2
\end{subcaptiongroup}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:mHCN2_dime}]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}%
}
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2}]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}%
}

\caption{Structure of the channel tetramer in the ligand-free state, viewed parallel to the membrane (A) or from the extracellular side (B). Each subunit is shown in a different color. Gray bars represent approximate boundaries of the membrane bilayer.}

\label{fig:mHCN2}
  \end{figure}
  
\subref{fig:mHCN2_dime} \subref{fig:a}
\subref{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2} \subref{fig:b}

\ref{fig:mHCN2_dime} \ref{fig:a}
\ref{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2} \ref{fig:b}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\ref{fig:a}`  and `\ref{fig:b}` (missing in your code).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}        

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
        \centering
        \sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:mHCN2_dime}]%
        {
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}%
        }
        \hfill
        \sidesubfloat[  \label{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2}]%
        {
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}%
        }
        
        \caption{Structure of the channel tetramer in the ligand-free state, viewed parallel to the membrane (A) or from the extracellular side (B). Each subunit is shown in a different color. Gray bars represent approximate boundaries of the membrane bilayer.}
                    \label{fig:mHCN2}
    \end{figure}

See subfigures~\ref{fig:a}  and \ref{fig:b}.    
    
\end{document}
```