# standalone class and floatrow package: irrevocably incompatible?

Tags: standalone, incompatibility, floatrow

The compilation of the following MCE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=15cm,float=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  A nice graphic!
  \caption{What a nice graphic!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

fails with the following error:

```
[...]
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.8 \end{figure}
                
?
```

Are the `standalone` class and the `floatrow` package irrevocably incompatible?

Comment: why would you want a float in standalone?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I should have specified that I use `standalone` with its `float=false` option. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I also tried [class=article] with no success.  I suspect that whatever code standalone uses for figure (which in earlier versons had been undefined) is incompatible with the changes made by floatrow.  Then again, not being able to use floatrow is hardly a loss.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About the floats in `standalone` (*class*), I have to insert figures with captions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why not being able to use `floatrow` is hardly a loss? It provides nice features, despite its age.

Comment: Floatrow does nothing that can't be done without it (albeit with a little more effort) and it has nasty side effects.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Taking in account the numerous and not obvious features of `floatrow`, “little” in “little more effort” looks optimistic, isn't it? :) About the nasty side effects, none I'm aware of but pointers are welcome.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C29.8901. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643659/how-to-subreference-in-floatrow-package-hyperref/643703?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C29.1599#643703, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410836/vertical-alignment-of-table-and-figure-placed-side-by-side-in-two-column-mode/410902?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C25.3734#410902  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591115/how-to-put-side-caption-in-a-figure-that-is-wrapped-inside-a-a-text.  Other links too long for comment.